# Rspec mock return value of multiple dimensions array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I need to mock a return value from a specific inner key in my array.
I want to mock this:

```
CONFIG['key1']['key2']
```

I thought of doing something like this:

```
allow(CONFIG).to receive(:[], :[]).with('key1', 'key2').and_return(['my mock'])
```

but this is not the right way to write it.

Does anyone knows how it should be written?
Thanks!

Comment: Is the array CONFIG created by the time you want to mock it?

Comment: Also consider that changing the code to make it easier to test may also make the code easier to work with in general. You might access the config through a method that takes two arguments for example, instead of accessing the raw config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i found the solution:

```
allow(CONFIG).to receive_message_chain(:[], :[]).with('key1').with('key2').and_return(['my mock'])
```